# How to printf a sint32 in C using gcc compiler tricore v3.4.6?

Tags: c, printf, signed-integer

I am working with the tricore v3.4.6 compiler.

Suppose I have a signed integer like `sint32 a = -1`
and want to print that with `printf`.

I tried `printf("Signed number %i", a)` as well as `printf("Signed number %d", a)` which both gives me compiler warnings, for example

warning: int format, sint32 arg

Comment: What is that `sint32` type?

Comment: What *is* `sint32`? A `typedef`? A `#define`? Where does it come from?

Comment: just a blind guess, try with `PRId32` ..

Comment: You can't just "have a signed integer like `RANDOM_TYPE_NAME`" in C, and ask about how that secret type interacts with standard library functions. Makes no sense.

Comment: What exactly is the compiler warning?

Comment: Can't we just call it an int32?

Comment: sint32 signed integer, 4 bytes. thought it is standard c - that is probably the solution to my  problem ...
compiler warning is "warning: int format, sint32 arg"

Comment: try `printf("%d %h", a, (void*)(double)a);`

Comment: all integers are signed by default, only the unsigned ones get a special letter - and become `uint32` for instance... thats why this `sint32` looks very strange.

Comment: Downvoted, because question is missing complete compiler error message. Also specify what compiler you are using. And edit the question to include relevant information, instead of using hard to read comments.

Comment: compiler used GNU GCC compiler for TriCore v3.4.6

Comment: ok, printf("Signed number %ld", a) worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlike suggested in the comments to the question, `sint32` is not uncommon in safety critical and embedded systems and usually falls back to a typecast for `int`. (e.g. in some [MISRA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA-C) environments).

Hence

```
sint32 a = -1;
printf("%d", a);
```

should do the trick anyways. tested with gcc v5.2.1 and arm-gcc v5.2.1 (-Wall and no warnings).

If it still gives you a warning try to figure out what `sint32` really maps to and try `long`-print: `printf("%ld")`. However, then double check if the byte length of `sint32` really is 32bits? (and some systems may even have less than a 32bit architecture)

Comment: as mentioned in the comments above, yes printf("%ld") works for me without warning.

Answer (score 0):

To `printf()` *any* signed integer that lacks a *defined* matching prefix like `"l"`, `"ll"`, `"h"`, etc. , simply cast to the widest known type.

```
#include <stdint.h>
sint32 a = -1;
printf("Signed number %jd", (intmax_t) a);

// or lacking intmax_t
sint32 a = -1;
printf("Signed number %lld", (long long) a);
```